# C# What is the speediest technique for IsStringMadeOf method?

Tags: string, c#-4.0, extension-methods

I have a method which is called thousands of times, but it is currently very slow to run. Is there a better technique? Unsafe methods are allowed.

It simply checks letters of input string whether it could be made of the letters of other string, like an anagram checker.

This is what my method currently looks like.

```
public static bool IsStringMadeOf(this string str, string from)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        int index = from.IndexOf(str[i]);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            from = from.Remove(index, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For my test cases, the results should be as follows:

```
str    | from        | result
-------------------------------
SLOW   | WSOL        | true
SLOW   | WTOL        | false
ASIA   | XZYABSTRIB  | false
ASIA   | XZYABSTRIAB | true
```

Answer (score 3):

To start with, you've got a *lot* of string operations here - you're creating lots of new strings by removing a single character each time, and you're using `IndexOf` a lot too.

I would start *very* simply - just sort the characters in each string, and then see if the sequences are equal:

```
public static bool IsStringMadeOf(this string str, string from)
{
    if (str.Length != from.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    char[] strArray = str.ToCharArray();
    char[] fromArray = from.ToCharArray();
    Array.Sort(strArray);
    Array.Sort(fromArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (strArray[i] != fromArray[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

That will certainly help a lot if you have long strings. For short strings, the creation of the `char` arrays may end up dominating... but that's at least what I'd try to start with.

Note that the above is a slightly optimized form of this LINQ version:

```
public static bool IsStringMadeOf(this string str, string from)
{
    if (str.Length != from.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return str.OrderBy(c => c).SequenceEqual(from.OrderBy(c => c));
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say, lengths must not be same. IsStringMadeOf("ABAC", "BNMKLAOBAC") returns true, ...("ABA","ABFDED") returns false

Comment: @EmreAtaseven: Well that does change things completely... so you'd need enough duplicates of each letter within the second string (e.g. "ABAC", "ABC" would have to return false) but the second string can contain unused letters? That really is a completely different request from how I'd read the question - I'd strongly encourage you to clarify the existing question and make sure you ask more clearly in the future. It would also be very helpful if you would clarify the expected string length and also which characters are used. (If it's only A-Z for example, that makes a huge difference.)